# Eclipse RCP and using org.eclipse.ui.activities to filter UI

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, filter, rcp, helios

I am leveraging org.eclipse.ui.activities and have been successful thanks to [this guide](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/).

However, I am having a problem applying this strategy to CTabItems. These are tabs within a CTabFolder which is in a PageBookView.

I can filter out PageBookView easily because it has a clear ID being set by static String.

I cannot find a way to assign an ID to the CTabItem which I can reference in my 'activityPatternBinding'.

Any advice is most welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PageBookView doesn't support activities. So you cannot filter out the individual pages by using activities. If you have a good use case, [raise a bug](http://bit.ly/NewBugInPlatformUI)